# I've derived a class from the list type. But index slicing on my class returns a Python list object, instead of my own object

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, inheritance

I have a class called AudioBuffer that is derived from Python's list type.

Before you ask, yes, I *did* pass the necessary parameters up the parent chain.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AudioBuffer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Everything works like a charm. I can use all list functionality including indexing.

The problem is: **When I use index slicing on my objects, the returning object is a "list", instead of my AudioBuffer.**

Example:

```
foo = AudioBuffer([15, 25, 35])
foo[1:].methodFromAudioBuffer()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'methodFromAudioBuffer'
```

Now, `AudioBuffer(foo[1:]).methodFromAudioBuffer` comes to mind. But that creates a new instance of AudioBuffer. And I don't want that. I want a reference to my original object, because I want to modify parts of it. Just like Python's native index slicing functionality.

Thank you.

Comment: While I know nothing of Python I assume that the slicing is a language or list facility which is defined to return a list. That facility knows nothing of your class and thus returns a list. (Btw, I think it is a dup, the answer in @sedders123 link seems entirely relevant.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Thanks for that piece of wisdom, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’d need to override the `__getitem__` method:

```
class AudioBuffer(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(AudioBuffer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return AudioBuffer(list.__getitem__(self, key))

    def methodFromAudioBuffer(self):
        print("my list is", self)

>>> foo = AudioBuffer([15, 25, 35])
>>> foo[1:].methodFromAudioBuffer()
my list is [25, 35]
```

Also it is recommended when subclassing a sequence to subclass [`collections.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence).

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the advice on MutableSequence. I'll definitely do that from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `__getitem__(self, key)` and there return your class.

From the Python documentation:

> Called to implement evaluation of self[key]. For sequence types, the
>   accepted keys should be integers and slice objects. Note that the
>   special interpretation of negative indexes (if the class wishes to
>   emulate a sequence type) is up to the **getitem**() method. If key is
>   of an inappropriate type, TypeError may be raised; if of a value
>   outside the set of indexes for the sequence (after any special
>   interpretation of negative values), IndexError should be raised. For
>   mapping types, if key is missing (not in the container), KeyError
>   should be raised.

When you call `obj[0]` this is syntactic sugar for `obj.__getitem__(0)`. Therefore just override the `__getitem__` of your class to return an instance of your class instead.